# Setting a label's text depending on the item selected in a combobox (QT/C++)

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, label, qt-creator

I'm new to QT creator and I was wondering if you could give me a hand with a little issue I have. 
I have a combobox which I have items such as "completely new" and "amateur". I also have a label which I want a specific number to appear in the label depending on the item selected in the combobox. For example:
Combobox("completely new") = label("11")
I'm not entirely sure how I would code this. My attempt is below, but it's error riddled, apologies.

```
if(ui->comboBox->itemData(ui->comboBox->"Completely new"){
       ui->labelThreshold->setText("11");
   }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Sorry, it's hard without a basic C++ knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (ui->comboBox->currentText() == "Completely new") {
    ui->labelThreshold->setText("11");
}
```

also you can put into the index custom item data.
Something like that

```
ui->comboBox->insertItem(0, "Completely new");
ui->comboBox->setItemData(0, "11");

ui->labelThreshold->setText(ui->comboBox->itemData(ui->comboBox->currentIndex).toString());
```